# CMake rejects a second target_link_libraries talking about "keyword" vs "plain"

Tags: cmake, build-dependencies

I'm compiling a binary, and I want to add its dependency libraries in two different `target_link_libraries()` commands for various reasons.

My commands look like this:

```
target_link_libraries(my_prog PRIVATE foo bar)
target_link_libraries(my_prog baz)
```

and I get the error:

```
  The keyword signature for target_link_libraries has already been used with
  the target "my_prog".  All uses of target_link_libraries with a target
  must be either all-keyword or all-plain.

  The uses of the keyword signature are here:

   * tests/CMakeLists.txt:10 (target_link_libraries)
```

What does this mean? What should I do?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Your use of `target_link_libraries()` is indeed problematic, as it involves two different "flavors" of this command, a traditional and a newer one.

In one use, you specify the dependency is `PRIVATE`; in the other, you specify nothing. That's not acceptable: Either you specify `PUBLIC`/`PRIVATE`/`INTERFACE` for *all* elements, or for none.

So, you can fix your `CMakeLists.txt` to say either:

```
target_link_libraries(my_prog foo bar)
target_link_libraries(my_prog baz)
```

or

```
target_link_libraries(my_prog PRIVATE foo bar)
target_link_libraries(my_prog PRIVATE baz)
```